# What do you call a painting that was created specifically on order from a client?

Tags: word-choice

What do you call the painting created for a client order?

Comment: A [commissioned](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/commission) painting.

Comment: Or just a *commission.* (See sense 1.2 in Lawrence's link.)

Comment: "commissioned" is the likely word you're looking for, but in some applications, it could be referred to as a "custom" painting.

Answer (score 3):

Fixer1234 said it in the comments but it has not been submitted as an answer yet, so i will pretend that i have been commissioned to post an answer.

commissioned.

dictionary.com
 18. to give a commission or order for: 
The owners commissioned a painting for the building's lobby.

example sentence:

> While visiting a museum yesterday i over heard a tour guide addressing a group of tourists, she said
>   "This is one of Joe Blow's commissioned paintings circa 1946, it was commissioned by the Lady Uppity Fancy Pants to commemorate the birth of her son, the heir apparent to the title of CEO for the -  Oligarchs Trump Democracy corporation  ".

Disclaimer:

> fixer1234 is in no way affiliated with or associated with or has had any communication with Alaska Man.

Comment: Well done. The model on which this site operates requires answers to be posted as answers. You have gone to the trouble of doing that properly. But your disclaimer, while amusing, is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities not previously listed include, but not limited to , "pre-order, acquisition, asset, or valuable depending on context, commissionary".